# Is there a possibility to create a "sticky" notification on the Google Home Hub?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home, google-assist-api

**EDIT**: To give a better example of the expected result.

I couldn't find a better place to ask this question.

Is there a way to create a card on the home screen? I am not talking about the BasicCard or any of the other responses that can be found on this [link](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#nodejs) . I am talking about for example the one from [image: Spotify]
or this google maps example [image: maps] or like this calendar example [image: calendar] or the one from google news or youtube.

I am looking for a way to show a status on the home/main screen. Not inside my app

At first, I thought it was a push notification of some sort but they don't seem to work in the Google Home Hub because they are working on the smartphone.

This is the push notification code. I basically mirrored [this](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications) guide

```
app.intent('Request Notification Permission', (conv: DialogflowConversation, params, input: string) => {
  console.log('in Request Notification Permission');
  conv.ask(new UpdatePermission({
    intent: 'Get Status'
  }));
  return conv;
});

app.intent('Finish_notification', (conv: DialogflowConversation, params, input: string) => {
  console.log('in Finish notification');
  if (conv.arguments.get('PERMISSION')) {
    conv.close(`Ok, I'll start alerting you.`);
  } else {
    conv.ask("There is no permission")
  }
  return conv;
});
```

---

**Prefered result**

A card on the home screen to show the state of e.g.: sensors that I have in my house. I am not necessarily talking about a media card this is just an example of a home screen card.

Comment: I believe media responses will create a media response card, but notifications generally aren't supported on smart displays.

Comment: It does not have to be a media card. Let's say that I have a few sensors in my house and I want to show their state on the home screen.

Comment: I have edited the original question

Comment: Smart home devices appear in the Home View section, with a swipe from the top of the screen.

Comment: @NickFelker that is not really what I am looking for

Comment: Updated the post again with more images